# Is there any way to whitelist .appspot.com so I can set a cookie on that domain in Firefox 6?

Tags: google-app-engine, firefox, cookies, tld

In order to test some stuff, I've been using the trick of setting a cookie on the .appspot.com domain, which allows me to share data between two different .appspot.com GAE apps.  This has stopped working in Firefox 6, and a google person told me:

> It's because appspot.com was added to the public suffix list of
>   domains that modern browsers should not allow cookies to be set for:
>   http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

which totally makes sense for regular users. But for my testing, I'd really like to have FF treat .appspot.com as a regular domain, not an "effective TLD". Is there any way to "whitelist" .appspot.com or otherwise override the effective_tld_names.dat used within FF?

(I need a hack that will work on OS X, in case that matters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, there is no supported way to do this. I checked the implementation of `nsCookieService` and method `SetCookieStringInternal` will reject any host names where it cannot get the base name from (which would be the case for "appspot.com" now - for the Firefox engine this is no longer a complete host name). This means that not even extensions can set a cookie for "appspot.com" other than by writing to the database "manually". But that doesn't help much here because method `GetCookiesFromHost` also uses the base domain for its checks so that any cookies for "appspot.com" will be ignored.

Given that effective_tld_names.dat is compiled into xul.dll the only way to change this data is using a hex editor on this file and for example replacing "appspot.com" by "bppspot.com" which should "disable" this rule. Note that a manipulation like this will break incremental updates and you will have to repeat it after the update.

Comment: Oh well.  For now we can still use our trick with Safari and Chrome, but it makes testing some stuff in FF a PITA.  Thanks.