# Using appspot.com as a partial domain cookie

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

I'm baffled over a recent problem I'm having with use of a partial domain name cookies. I'm using partial domain cookies in my app to manage a single sign-on scenario. Everything was working fine until I happened to try it with the Google App Engine domain `appspot.com`.

Try as I may, I could not get the browser to accept `appspot.com` as a partial domain cookie. Here is the HTTP response header I am sending:

```
foo=bar;Path=/;Domain=.appspot.com
```

If my app is at `http://my.appspot.com` the browser ignores the set cookie. I can do this with other domains (e.g. `google.com`) and all is well (I am using my hosts file to direct the browser to my mac). It fails when I run it locally, on App Engine, or anywhere else.

I can't think of any reason this domain name would be special. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to whitelist .appspot.com so I can set a cookie on that domain in Firefox 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110681/is-there-any-way-to-whitelist-appspot-com-so-i-can-set-a-cookie-on-that-domain)

Comment: This would be an enormous security/privacy issue if it were possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2387) might answer your question.

To quote:

> I tested. It is not possible for a page of child domain to create a
>   cookie for parent domain. Hence this issue dont exist.

Further clarification that might help; according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/QPW6dOLmRfo/EopRQ4nFk8YJ) Google Groups thread:

> It appears that I cannot set a cookie with domain=.appspot.com
>
> When I do that, it doesn't show up in the list of cookies.  I can set
>   a cookie in a sub-domain of .appspot.com (domain=foo.appspot.com) but
>   not on appspot.com itself.

And Jon McAlister's reply:

> It's because appspot.com was added to the public suffix list of
>   domains that modern browsers should not allow cookies to be set for:
>   see
>   [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1)

Comment: Bang.  You got it Jon.  I verified the same problem with other domains in the public suffix list.  Thanks!!!